# MySQL BigInt max value stored in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, biginteger

I'm trying to store the MySQL BigInt maximum value (`18446744073709551615`) into a javascript variable but when I do so the value change to `18446744073709552000` and I don't know why.

So I was wondering if anyone could explain me why it's happenning and if there is some way to store `18446744073709551615` into a javascript variable.

```js
let bob = 18446744073709551615;
console.log(bob);
```

Comment: That value cannot be represented accurately in a JavaScript number. You can store it as a string, though that's probably not very useful.

Comment: `let bob = '18446744073709551615';` JavaScript numbers are always 64-bit floating point. You could then convert to a [big](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big.js) number type.

Comment: So if it's a 64-bit floating point I should be able to store 2^63-1 in a javascript variable? (`9223372036854775807`)

Comment: Part of the 64 bits are used as an exponent. For exact integer values you only have the range of ±2^53-1.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this package for arbitrary-precision integers:

https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js